# powershell breaking my string

Tags: sql, powershell

Powershell breaks my strings when I have specifically told it to put the carriage return at the end of the line

I have PS script that is supposed to write a batch sql insert in groups of 100:

```
function WriteBatch {
    echo $sql
    $Command.CommandText = $sql
        $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$server = "norcrpsqldev08"
$Database = "SandBoxVinny"
$Path = "Y:\BMPS"
$Counter = 0

$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
[string]$sql =     "
                begin 
                    insert into TestPowerShell(NameString, FileSize, Mode, Directory, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime)
                    values " 

foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Verbose -Recurse -Path $Path | Select-Object  Name, Length, Mode, Directory, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime) {
    $fileName = $file.Name
    $fileSize = ([int]$file.Length)
    $fileMode = $file.Mode
    $fileDirectory = $file.Directory
    $fileCreationTime = [datetime]$file.CreationTime
    $fileLastAccessTime = [datetime]$file.LastAccessTime
    $fileLastWriteTime = [datetime]$file.LastWriteTime
    $sql = $sql + "('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileMode', '$fileDirectory', '$fileCreationTime', '$fileLastAccessTime', '$fileLastWriteTime'),`r`n"
    #$sql += "`n"
    $Counter++

    If($Counter -eq 100) {
        $sql = $sql.Trim().Trim(',')
        $sql = $sql + " End"
        WriteBatch
        $Counter = 0
        $sql = "
                begin 
                    insert into TestPowerShell(NameString, FileSize, Mode, Directory, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime)
                    values " 
    }

}

if ($Counter -gt 0){
    $sql = $sql.Trim().Trim(',')
    $sql = $sql + " End"
    WriteBatch
}

$Connection.Close()
```

The resulting strings often have a line break where it is not supposed to be:

Results:

```
    ('PCA - implementation demand post transfer 9.14.16.xlsx', '56191', '-a---', 'Y:\BMPS\Salesforce\Projects\Merging PCA org into RCA\Data Move\Data\Final Move\Final upload\Compare reports', '09/14/2016 17:46:30', '09/14/2016 17:52:08', '09/14/2016 17:52:08'),
('RCA - implementation demand post transfer 9.14.16_bad.xlsx', '55442', '-a---', 'Y:\BMPS\Salesforce\Projects\Merging PCA org into RCA\Data Move\Data\Final Move\Final upload\Compare reports', '09/14/2016 17:46:30', '09/14/2016 17:46:55', '09/14/2016 17:46:55'
),
('RCA System - post transfer 9.14.16 No account.xlsx', '40498', '-a---', 'Y:\BMPS\Salesforce\Projects\Merging PCA org into RCA\Data Move\Data\Final Move\Final upload\Compare reports', '09/14/2016 17:20:37', '09/14/2016 17:26:49', '09/14/2016 17:26:49'),
```

This should look like this:

```
    ('PCA - implementation demand post transfer 9.14.16.xlsx', '56191', '-a---', 'Y:\BMPS\Salesforce\Projects\Merging PCA org into RCA\Data Move\Data\Final Move\Final upload\Compare reports', '09/14/2016 17:46:30', '09/14/2016 17:52:08', '09/14/2016 17:52:08'),
('RCA - implementation demand post transfer 9.14.16_bad.xlsx', '55442', '-a---', 'Y:\BMPS\Salesforce\Projects\Merging PCA org into RCA\Data Move\Data\Final Move\Final upload\Compare reports', '09/14/2016 17:46:30', '09/14/2016 17:46:55', '09/14/2016 17:46:55'),
('RCA System - post transfer 9.14.16 No account.xlsx', '40498', '-a---', 'Y:\BMPS\Salesforce\Projects\Merging PCA org into RCA\Data Move\Data\Final Move\Final upload\Compare reports', '09/14/2016 17:20:37', '09/14/2016 17:26:49', '09/14/2016 17:26:49'),
```

This breaks my sql.  Any thoughts?

Comment: where are you viewing the results at?  In Text Editor, cmd window?  Is it possible they are simply wrapping due to string length and the program?

Comment: Your SQL is broken anyway. Don't build SQL statements by string concatenation. It makes you vulnerable to SQL injection (`');DROP TABLES;--` is valid in a filename).

Comment: This is a one time internal use script.  Trashed once the project is done.  Thank you for the info though @AnsgarWiechers and we have no file names matching that sql inj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize= @{Width=5000;Height=100}
```

On older versions of PowerShell you may need:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize=New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(5000, 100)
```

Comment: This should avoid wrapping on strings up to 5000 character, at the expense of some virtual memory.   Obviously the choice of values is up to you.   P.S.  chances are if this works, your $sql string is **not** broken, just the display wrapped as Matt suggested.

Comment: I get this:
`Exception setting "BufferSize": "Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "System.Management.Automation.Host.Size"."
At C:\LocalSourceSave\Datamap\PowerShellDatamapTextv3.ps1:1 char:16
+ $Host.UI.RawUI. <<<< BufferSize= @{Width=5000;Height=100}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException`

Comment: Sounds like a powershell version difference, I'm running 5.1.   Give me a minute...

Comment: Will this choke with inserting up to 500k rows because of eating up the virtual memory?  It seems to work just fine.

Comment: No problem, it doesn't effect the operation of your script, just display of output. .

Comment: @Burt_Harris Add that into the answer. It is important to note.